# Switch Read Session to Publish Session in Facebook Android SDK 3.0

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Do I really need to close a session (say from a READ session), and build a new active session of PUBLISH, in order for me to execute publish_stream request.

If so (or not), is there any effective way for me to do so?

Answer (score 2):

Not required.
Just call `session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS));`

where PERMISSIONS is(change it accordingly):

```
    private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
```

Once done, you will get the callback:

```
SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED
```

Check for the above state & post your messgae again by calling:

```
Request statusRequest=Request.newStatusUpdateRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), mStatus.getText().toString(), reqestCallback);
if(statusRequest!=null){
statusRequest.executeAsync();
```

Comment: is this version 3.0?
session.openForRead(...); then session.requestNewPublishPermission(...), I will get an error.

Comment: What is the error that you get? Please update your question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private class App_Session_StatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback
    {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) 
        {
            Log.d("asd", "state changed");
            handleSessionStateChanged(session, state, exception);
        }
    }

    private void handleSessionStateChanged(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)
    {
        if(state == SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED)
        {
            Request statusRequest=Request.newStatusUpdateRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), mStatus.getText().toString(), reqestCallback);
            if(statusRequest!=null){
                statusRequest.executeAsync();
            }
        }

        if(session != null)
        {
            if(session.isOpened())
            {
                Log.d("asd", "session is opened");

                Log.d("asd", "Token = " + session.getAccessToken());
                Log.d("asd", "Expiry = " + session.getExpirationDate().toGMTString());
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("asd", "session is NOT opened");
            }
        }
    }

    Session.getActiveSession().requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, Arrays.asList("publish_actions")));
```